# Custom comments for viewset in api documentation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I have django rest framework api application and generate documentation for it. I use api view with viewset and I have custom method. In urls I use routers. For generate documentation I use DRF Docs.

My view:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """View for user object.
    """
    ...

    @detail_route(methods=["post"])
    def set_password(self, request, pk=None):
       """View to set new password
       """
       ...
```

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from accounts.views import UserViewSet


__all__ = ["accounts_urlpatterns"]


accounts_router = DefaultRouter()
accounts_router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)


accounts_urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^accounts/', include(accounts_router.urls))
]
```

My api documentation result:
[image]

I want custom comments for set_password method and display different fields because I use for this method other serializer. How can I do that?